# Code Jam 2018 Trouble Sort

Tags: sorting, bubble-sort

So, Code Jam 2018 Qualification round ended today and the for Second problem 'Trouble Sort', I got the right program but in the judging process, I didn't get it as it said that I exceeded the time limit, but there were no time limit specifications in the question.
Can someone help me with the proper code?
Question: https://codejam.withgoogle.com/2018/challenges/

Comment: The competition is over. I posted the question after it was over. I can't cheat. I just wanna know the actual solution.

Answer (score 2):

> but there were no time limit specifications in the question

You were not careful enough reading the [problem statement](https://codejam.withgoogle.com/2018/challenges/00000000000000cb/dashboard/00000000000079cb).

---

#### Test set 1 (Visible)

3 ≤ **N** ≤ 100.
Time limit (for the entire test set): 10 seconds.

#### Test set 2 (Hidden)

3 ≤ **N** ≤ 10<sup>5</sup>.
Time limit (for the entire test set): 20 seconds.

---

You can also read the [analysis of the problem](https://codejam.withgoogle.com/2018/challenges/00000000000000cb/analysis/00000000000079cb)